# how to connect a postgresql with dbeaver (21.0.0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am newbie with ubuntu and trying to working with this one. And here is my problem.

I create a new program in rails with database by this command

```
rails new freelancer --database=postgresql
```

Everthing woking fine, seems I got a postgresql database with rails.

My problem is, I do not know how to connect my database to the dbeaver program, btw, if I run those command `rails db:setup` and `rails db:migrate` after connect my database to dbeave program, it can make some new database ?

And finally can you show me how to start and stop the server too ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your database connection is specified on your `config/database.yml`, under your project folder, one block for each environment, but by default you will be using development env.

If you haven't done anything else than what you commented (and you did it right hehe), your database should be already created with name `freelancer_development`, and you just need to connect to it using DBeaber. Create a new connection using PostgreSQL adapter (check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRdl0P4V-PU)) and following data:

- Host: `localhost`
- Port: `5432`
- Database: `freelancer_development`
- User: `[YOUR_POSTGRES_USER]`
- Password: `[YOUR_POSTGRES_PASSWORD]`

If you don't know your Postgres user. Try with following combinations, if none of them works, you'll need to setup one.

| User | Password |
| --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres |
| postgres |  |
| [YOUR_UBUNTU_USER_NAME] |  |

To start your Rails server, just run `rails s` (short for `rails server`) on your terminal while being inside your project folder, and hit `Ctrl+C` to stop it.